# Severe error occurred on the current command when trying to insert from linked server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-insert, linked-server

I'm working with SQL Server 2008 SP3 and trying to insert about 200K rows from a linked server but, after a while I get this error:

```
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

This error happens:

- Almost always, but sometimes it works right.
- Not when SELECT is limited to a TOP(10).
- Sometimes when I execute the SELECT joining to the local table.

Thing I've checked out:

- I can get all rows from linked server without the JOIN.
- Done CHECKDB in all databases on local and linked server, no errors.
- CHKDSK in all disks on local and linked server, no errors.

This is the target table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TargetTable](
    [ProdID] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [Download] [bigint] NULL,
    [ImageID] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [ImageWeight] [int] NULL,
    [ImageWidth] [int] NULL,
    [ImageHeight] [int] NULL,
    [ImageAngle] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [MfPN] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [ContentGuid] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [MediaTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MimeType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [URL] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [_DateLastUpdated] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

And this is the query I use to insert

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TargetTable]
(
    [ProdID],
    [Download],
    [ImageID],
    [ImageWeight],
    [ImageWidth],
    [ImageHeight],
    [ImageAngle],
    [MfPN],
    [ContentGuid],
    [MediaTypeID],
    [MimeType],
    [URL],
    [Timestamp],
    [_DateLastUpdated]
)
SELECT
    i.ProdID
    ,i.Download
    ,i.ImageID
    ,i.ImageWeight
    ,i.ImageWidth
    ,i.ImageHeight
    ,i.ImageAngle
    ,i.MfPN
    ,i.ContentGuid
    ,i.MediaTypeID
    ,i.MimeType
    ,i.[Url]
    ,i.[Timestamp]
    ,i._DateLastUpdated

FROM [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[view_Source] i WITH(NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN [LocalDatabase].[dbo].[TargetTable] t WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON i.ContentGuid = t.ContentGuid AND i.ProdID= t.ProdID
WHERE
    t.ContentGuid IS NULL
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: May be command timeout issue

Comment: Thank you @HiteshKansagara but I've checked on SSMS that timeout is set to "0".

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log. There might be an exception.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur when trying to read data that is also changing, without using a lock. Remove the WITH(NOLOCK) table hint.

Even when the underlying data is not changing, reading uncommitted data is risky, and [not recommended](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/08/but-nolock-is-okay-when-the-data-isnt-changing-right/):

> With NOLOCK, you can:
>
> - See rows twice
> - Skip rows altogether
> - See data that was never committed
> - And have your query fail with an error
> - If you’re cool with that, great – NOLOCK is for you.