# SQL Server Error: Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-administration

When I ran the below query in SQL Server 2016 Getting the below-mentioned error.

Query:

```
DECLARE @INCR_DATE DATETIME

SET @INCR_DATE = (SELECT DATEADD(DD, -1, MIN(DT)) 
                  FROM
                      (SELECT MAX(Record_Updated_Datetime) AS DT 
                       FROM [LINKEDSERVER].Test.dbo.Customer WITH(NOLOCK)
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT MAX(Record_Updated_Datetime) AS DT 
                       FROM STAGE.dbo.Customer WITH(NOLOCK) 
                       WHERE [Source] = 'TEST') INCR)
```

Error:

> Msg 596, Level 21, State 1, Line 38
>   Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 38
>   A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

When I ran the Select statement individually it is working fine. But when I ran with `UNION ALL`, it is throwing this error.

Also, it is giving error only in one machine (eg.QA) in DEV and PROD box query is running fine.

What could be the issue?

NOTE: DEV, QA, PROD - Same server settings

Comment: Deadlocked? Someone killed the SPID? How does the Linked Server come into play here? Is that another test/dev machine? Probably better to find this in QA than PROD.

Comment: Yeah, analyzing in QA machine. No deadlocks and no one is killing the SPID.

Comment: Look in the SQL Server Logs, and make sure that your SQL Server instance is fully patched.

Comment: Yeah sure, will have a look on it.

Comment: Take a look here : https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/checkdb-cannot-continue-the-execution-because-the-session-is-in-the-kill-state

Comment: This is because you're using NOLOCK. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67801882/2440).